# Create a new unique file

Tags: file-system, go

For debugging purposes I am storing requests into files. This code is supposed to create a new file for each request.

Somehow it doesn't look very nice, can it be improved? Additionally it would be nice if it could be made atomic.

```
filenamePrefix := exeDir + "/debug/" + time.Now().Format("20060102150405")
var filename string

for i := 0 ; ; i++ {
    if (i > 100) {
        log.Print("Could not find free filename")
        return
    }

    filename = filenamePrefix + "-" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    _, err := os.Stat(filename);
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        break
    }
}

fd, err := os.Create(filename)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err.Error())
    return
}
defer fd.Close()

io.Copy(fd, request.Body)
```

Comment: I know nothing about Go, but [Google says](http://www.google.com/?#q=go+golang+unique+file+name) you might use [`TempFile()` from `ioutil`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile). See also ['Golang Generate Unique Filename With Extension'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005865/) at StackOverflow and ['Create a temporary file'](http://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/81467564564/create-a-temporary-file) at Golang Examples.

Comment: @CiaPan I want to have sequential names.

Answer (score 7):

Your code has a few items in it which concern me in a few small ways, and, in general, while I think your code is OK functionally, it could be done better (I am biased, I have done similar things, and ended up doing it differently).

First up, my concerns...

### Timestamp function

while it is a 1-liner, I would still have a method to encapsulate the time formatting:

```
func buildFileName() string {
    return time.Now().Format("20060102150405")
}
```

### `filepath`

You should use `path/filepath` to manage your path names:

```
import (
  "path/filepath"
)

filenamePrefix := filepath.Join(exeDir, "debug", buildFileName())
```

### Functions

You need more functions... still. I would create a function to control the file creation process (note the use of `%d` instead of `string.Itoa`...):

```
func pickFileName(prefix string) (string, error) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fname := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%d", prefix, i)
        if _, err := os.Stat(fname); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return fname, nil
        }
    }
    return "", fmt.Errorf("Unable to create a unique file with the prefix %v in 100 tries", prefix)
}
```

### Result

OK, now your code looks like:

```
filenamePrefix := filepath.Join(exeDir, "debug", buildFileName())
filename, err := pickFileName(filenamePrefix)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return
}

fd, err := os.Create(filename)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return
}
defer fd.Close()

io.Copy(fd, request.Body)
```

### Error handling

You have `log.Print(err.Error())` but `log.Print(err)` is fine. Still, you should probably be returning an error, instead of just logging it....

## Alternative

If it were me, I would do two things.....

First up, create a directory for the actual process you are running as.

```
myid := fmt.SPrintf("Process_%d", os.Getpid())
```

then, ensure you use that in your path:

```
filenamePrefix := filepath.Join(exeDir, "debug", myid, buildFileName())
```

Now, you have a folder dedicated to the current process (and collisions with other running instances of your process are impossible - at the same time - though there may be an old instance of that same folder for an older process - that's OK).

Then, create a counter (a "global") too:

```
var debugCounter uint64
```

And a matching function:

```
func nextDebugId() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", atomic.AddUint64(&debugCounter, 1))
}
```

Now, you can simplify the whole thing (by modifying `buildFileName`) to:

```
func buildFileName() string {
    return time.Now().Format("20060102150405") + "_" + nextDebugId()
}
```

and your whole code then becomes:

```
fullpath := filepath.Join(exeDir, "debug", myid, buildFileName())

fd, err := os.Create(fullpath)
.....
```